# Sorting list of tuples representing cards by alphabet and then rank

Tags: python, function, sorting, tuples, bubble-sort

I want to sort a hand of cards by alphabetical order first (Club, Diamond, Heart, Spade) and then by rank (Ace to King). I have the following (very lengthy and inefficient) code but the output seems wrong. I feel like it is an issue with the bubble sort that I use. What am I missing here, and what would be a better way of doing this? For my final output I also will convert the 2, 11, 12, and 13 back to Ace, Jack, Queen and King but I really do not want to redo what I did to get them into a numerical value in the first place. The I/O should look like this:

Sample Input: [('h', 'q'), ('c', 'j'), ('d', '2'), ('s', '3'), ('h', '5'), ('d', 'j'), ('d', '10')]

Sample Output: [('c', 'j'), ('d', '2'), ('d', '10'), ('d', 'j'), ('h', '5'), ('h', 'q'), ('s', '3')]

Here is the code I have so far and the resulting output:

```
def sort_hand(hand):
    """
    Sorts the a hand of cards by the value of each suit/type of card. 
    """
    
    # A=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J=11,Q=12,K=13
    # UPDATING CARDS SO THAT THEY CAN BE ORDERED BY RANK
    new_hand = []
 
    # GIVING NUMERIC VALUES TO JACK, QUEEN, KING, AND ACE
    for element in hand: 
        if element[1] == 'j':
            val = element[1].replace('j', '11')
            new_element = (element[0], val)
            new_hand.append(new_element)
        elif element[1] == 'q':
            val = element[1].replace('q', '12')
            new_element = (element[0], val)
            new_hand.append(new_element)
        elif element[1] == 'k':
            val = element[1].replace('k', '13')
            new_element = (element[0], val)
            new_hand.append(new_element)
        elif element[1] == 'a':
            val = element[1].replace('a', '1')
            new_element = (element[0], val)
            new_hand.append(new_element)
        else:
            pass
            new_hand.append(element)
    
    # BUBBLE SORT USED TO ORDER BY RANK 
    for ix in range(1, len(new_hand)):
        value_to_sort = new_hand[ix][1]

        while new_hand[ix-1][1] > value_to_sort and ix > 0:
            new_hand[ix], new_hand[ix-1] = new_hand[ix-1], new_hand[ix]
            ix -= 1
            
    # MAKE SUBLISTS FOR EACH SUIT      
    c_list = []
    d_list = []
    h_list = []
    s_list = []
            
    for element in new_hand:
        if element[0] == 'c':
            c_list.append(element)
        elif element[0] == 'd':
            d_list.append(element)
        elif element[0] == 'h':
            h_list.append(element)
        else: 
            s_list.append(element)
    
    # COMBINE ORDERED SUIT SUBLISTS TO MAKE FINAL SORTED HAND BY RANK
    final_hand = c_list + d_list + h_list + s_list
            
    return final_hand

>>> hand = [('h', 'q'), ('c', 'j'), ('d', '2'), ('s', '3'), ('h', '5'), ('d', 'j'), ('d', '10')]  
>>> sort_hand(hand)
[('c', '11'),
 ('d', '10'),
 ('d', '11'),
 ('d', '2'),
 ('h', '12'),
 ('h', '5'),
 ('s', '3')]
```

I feel like I am close with this code, but not sure where to go from here. Would appreciate a well-explained answer, thank you.

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to update the loop variable inside the `for` loop. Instead of using `ix` as the loop variable in the `while` loop, introduce a new variable `jx` initialized as `jx = ix` and replace `ix` with `jx` everywhere inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lambda to sort with a dual key.

```
rank = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'j', 'q', 'k', 'a']
suit = ['c', 'd', 'h', 's']

inp = [('h', 'q'), ('c', 'j'), ('d', '2'), ('s', '3'), ('h', '5'), ('d', 'j'), ('d', '10')]

outp = sorted(inp,key = lambda x: 
    (suit.index(x[0]), rank.index(x[1])))

print(outp)
```

Output:

```
[('c', 'j'), ('d', '2'), ('d', '10'), ('d', 'j'), ('h', '5'), ('h', 'q'), ('s', '3')]
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I am familiar with lambda functions and single keys so far, so could you explain how the dual key works in this case? I recognize by (suit.index(x[0]), rank.index(x[1]) you are extracting the tuples by their suit and rank, but how does the sorting work in the background? Does it go by the 0th index first and then the 1st index?

Comment: When you use key=tuple, it will sort based on the order of the elements in the tuple. https://www.peterbe.com/plog/in-python-you-sort-with-a-tuple

Answer (score 2):

You can use the inbuilt `sort` or `sorted` functions to achieve this

The additional thing you would require with the above functions is the comparator logic , which can be supplied using the `key` paramter.

```
def sort_hand(inp):
  ##### I have created the order of the suites arbitrarily
  suite_map = {
     'h':1
     ,'c':2
     ,'s':3
     ,'d':4
  }

  rank_map = {
        'a':1
        'k':2
        'q':3
        'j':4
        '10':5
        '9':6
        '8':7
        '7':8
        '6':9
        '5':10
        '4':11
        '3':12
        '2':13
        '1':14
    }
    
    return suite_map[inp[0]],rank_map[inp[1]]
```

O/P --->

```
>>> hand
[('h', 'q'), ('c', 'j'), ('d', '2'), ('s', '3'), ('h', '5'), ('d', 'j'), ('d', '10')]
>>> sorted(hand,key=sort_hand)
[('h', 'q'), ('h', '5'), ('c', 'j'), ('s', '3'), ('d', 'j'), ('d', '10'), ('d', '2')]
```

You can control the lexicographical order based on the `suite_map` and `rank_map` as per your order and sort accordingly